# Un-wrap cells in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, table

Is there a way to turn all multiline (wrapped) cells in a table in org-mode into single-line (un-wrapped) cells?

The table I have:

```
|------------+----------+-----+-----|
|       DATE | DESCR    |  IN | OUT |
|------------+----------+-----+-----|
| 2023-10-17 | aaaaa    | 100 |     |
|            | bbbbb    |     |     |
|------------+----------+-----+-----|
| 2023-10-16 | ccccc    |     |  50 |
|            | ddddd    |     |     |
|            | eeeee    |     |     |
|------------+----------+-----+-----|
| 2023-10-15 | ffffffff |     |  25 |
|------------+----------+-----+-----|
```

the table I want to get:

```
|------------+-------------------+-----+-----|
|       DATE | DESCR             |  IN | OUT |
|------------+-------------------+-----+-----|
| 2023-10-17 | aaaaa bbbbb       | 100 |     |
|------------+-------------------+-----+-----|
| 2023-10-16 | ccccc ddddd eeeee |     |  50 |
|------------+-------------------+-----+-----|
| 2023-10-15 | ffffffff          |     |  25 |
|------------+-------------------+-----+-----|
```

Comment: Org mode tables do not support multiline cells - are you talking about [table.el tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html) perhaps?

Comment: I have a table in an org-mode buffer with cells in which text is wrapped; I don't know how to distinguish whether it is a "table.el table" or an "org-mode table"

Comment: Check the link above and see if it looks like what is shown there: if there is a `+` at an outer intersection, then it's a table.el table; Org mode tables uses `+` for internal intersections only.

Comment: You can always add a (small portion of a) table to your question to show how it looks: put it between lines with triple backticks.

Comment: I did not know this graphical difference between org-mode tables and table.el tables ... thanks! so "my table" is an org-mode table; if I try to convert it with org-table-convert the multiline cells are not un-wrapped but rows are added

Comment: The thing is that the `aaaaa` and the `bbbbb` are *SEPARATE* cells, i.e. cells are delimited horizontally with `|` symbols, but vertically they are *always* a single line: the separator lines are *NOT* cell boundaries - they are just decoration. That's in contrast to table.el tables where separator lines *are* vertical cell boundaries. So you need to combine different cells : I don't know of any way to scrunch two or more cells (i.e. two or more rows of a single column) into a single cell, other than cutting and pasting and then deleting the extra rows.

Comment: For now I used a macro to un-wrap cells but on longer tables I think I will write a python script! Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Just remember: you are *not* unwrapping a cell, you are combining different cells into a single cell. If you end up using Org mode tables a lot, the distinction is important.